# How do nested expressions work in groovy?

Tags: groovy

Right now I'm doing this:

```
// Returns a string that needs to be manipulated
def str = callSomeFunc arg1:'sdfsdf', arg2:'blah', arg3:'sdfs'
str = str.trim()
```

Because this doesn't work:

```
def str = (callSomeFunc arg1:'sdfsdf', arg2:'blah', arg3:'sdfs').trim()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [docs](http://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_omitting_parentheses):

> In some cases parentheses are required, such as when making nested
>   method calls or when calling a method without parameters.

In your case this will work also:

```
def str = callSomeFunc(arg1:'sdfsdf', arg2:'blah', arg3:'sdfs').trim()
```